# HttpResponseBase replacement in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a CustomJsonResult class shown below, which is written in ASP.NET MVC:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


namespace Web.Authentication
{
public class CustomJsonResult : JsonResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
        {
            response.ContentType = ContentType;
        }
        else
        {
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
        if (ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
        }
        if (Data != null)
        {                
            var isoConvert = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
            isoConvert.DateTimeFormat = _dateFormat;
            response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, isoConvert));
        }
    }
}
}
```

I converted this to ASP.NET Core MVC. For that I changed the `HttpResponseBase` to `HttpResponse` and added this namespace `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


namespace Web.Authentication
{
public class CustomJsonResult : JsonResult
{        
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
        {
            response.ContentType = ContentType;
        }
        else
        {
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
        if (ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
        }
        if (Data != null)
        {                
            var isoConvert = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
            isoConvert.DateTimeFormat = _dateFormat;
            response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data, isoConvert));
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm using this class in controller json method:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult GetDataRefreshDate()
    {            
        var response = ...
        return new CustomJsonResult()
        {
            Data = response,
            MaxJsonLength = 86753090
        };
    }
```

But After converting, I'm getting errors like

> The type or namespace name 'Script' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

> The name 'Data' does not exist in the current context

> 'HttpResponse' does not contain a definition for 'Write' and no accessible extension method 'Write' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpResponse' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

> The name 'ContentEncoding' does not exist in the current context

> 'CustomJsonResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: Are you sure you need this code *at all*? Dates are serialized using the ISO8601 format since Web API 1.0. That's the default format for all .NET Core applications, including ASP.NET Core MVC

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomJsonResult1 : JsonResult
    {

       
        public CustomJsonResult1(object value) : base(value)
        {
           
        }
        public int MaxJsonLength { get; set; }

        public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }
            HttpResponse response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
            {
                response.ContentType = ContentType;
            }
            else
            {
                response.ContentType = "application/json";
            }
            var mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(ContentType);
            if (mediaType.Encoding != null)
            {
                response.ContentType = response.ContentType;
            }

            if (Value != null)
            {
                var isoConvert = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
                isoConvert.DateTimeFormat = null;

                response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Value, isoConvert));
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

In controller：

```
return new CustomJsonResult1(new { result = false, msg = "???" });
```

There is no MaxJsonLength property in Jsonresult  class in asp.net core.
and the "Data"property is replaced with value propert

Comment: I tried above code. It shows no error now. But in controller method, what can be given in place of `Data = response` and `MaxJsonLength = 86753090`. Currently it shows this CustomJsonResult class does not contain definition for `Data` and `MaxJsonLength`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've updated my answer,please check it